# Apache RewriteEngine afetando tomcat - Ubuntu 16 server

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite

Estou com o seguinte problema.

Configurei o arquivo htaccess para que todas requisições sejam redirecionadas para utilização de ssl (https). Até então tudo funcionou corretamente, porém recentemente instalei o Tomcat no servidor e precisei "ignorar" o redirecionamento no caso de acesso pela porta 8080 (porta padrão do tomcat), modifiquei o arquivo htaccess da seguinte forma:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond "%{SERVER_PORT}" "!^8080$"
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,NC,R]

# Send / to /roundcube.
RewriteRule ^/?$ /roundcube [L]
```

Porém ao tentar acessar o dominio pelo navegador na porta 8080 "my.hostname.com.br:8080" ele reescreve a URL para "https://my.hostname.com.br:8080" gostaria que neste caso especifico nao houvesse nenhuma alteração ou seja quando acessado "my.hostname.com.br:8080" apenas acesse "http://my.hostname.com.br:8080" normalmente.

Como devo proceder?

Comment: Solução que encontrei foi criar um novo subdominio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após criado um novo subdomínio consegui fazer a configuração especifica do rewrite específica para o subdominio.

no arquivo "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf" inclui a seguinte tratativa.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName tomcat.mydomain.com

        ServerAdmin postmaster@mydomain.com
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =tomcat.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

Para mim resolveu, pois utilizar outro subdomínio exclusivo par ao tomcat ficou até melhor para mim.